Display different composable item in Multi type Lazy Column after every 5th Item in Jetpack Compose
I have two lists, number list of length 200 and and alphabet list of length 26. Both lists have different composable items to show them i.e NumberItem() and AlphabetItem().
I want AlphabetItem() to be displayed after every 5 items of NumberItem() in LazyColoumn.
My code and results:
    @Composable
fun LazyColumnWithMultipleTypesSample() {
    val numList = (1..200).toList()
    val alphabetList = ('A'..'Z').toList()
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(count = numList.size + alphabetList.size) { index ->



            if (index % 5 == 0 && index / 5 < alphabetList.size) { //for index=0 , index%5==0 is always true, hence we make sure index is not 0 so this item does not appear as first item
                // Display alphabet item
                AlphabetItem(
                    char = alphabetList[index / 5], //-1 so 0th index also be seen
                    onClick = { char ->
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Alphabet clicked: $char", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                )
            }
            // Display number item
            val numIndex = index
            if (numIndex < numList.size) //checking index overflow is not there
                NumberItem(
                    number = numList[numIndex],
                    onClick = { number ->
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Number clicked: $number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                )

        }
    }
}


Notice, the first AlphabetItem() is not in the 6th index but at the 0th index.
I want 5 items of NumberItem() then 1 AlphabetItem() and so on. If AlphabetList get exhausted show only numberItem after that.
I have tried, extra if(index>0) check for AlphabetItem() which loaded all items except for alphabet "A".

You can decrease index / 5 by 1 when calculating the index of alphabetList, so index 0 becomes -1, 5 becomes 0 and so on.
if (index % 5 == 0 && (index / 5 - 1) in 0..alphabetList.lastIndex) {
    AlphabetItem(
        char = alphabetList[index / 5 - 1],

Alteratively, create a range of acceptable indices and check against it.
val alphabetRange = 1..alphabetList.size
...
if (index % 5 == 0 && index / 5 in alphabetRange) {
    AlphabetItem(
        char = alphabetList[index / 5 - 1],



Hello, thanks for your answer. your solution is making list skip AlphabetItem() for "A" and showing from B to Z.
and when scrolling to bottom app crash for java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 26, Size: 26
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

I've just tried and it's working. Have you noticed the -1 in char = alphabetList[index / 5 - 1], ? @CodingDevil

Ya, It worked, marking this answer as "correct" answer. @Jan Itor

I think alphabetItem and numberItem share the same index might not be a good choice. It might cause some unexpected problem and make you suffer when debugging. For example,  if changing item count to items(count = 100), lazyColumn will produce 100 numberItem and 20 alphabetItem, it's 120 items.
code below is assigning a "item type" for each index and rendering difference type of item:
@Composable
fun LazyColumnWithMultipleTypesSample(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    numList: List<Int> = (0 until 200).toList(),
    alphabetList: List<Char> = ('A'..'Z').toList(),
    groupMemberCnt: Int = 6
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier) {
        items(count = numList.size + alphabetList.size) { idx ->
            //alphabet count before index idx
            val alphabetCntBefore = minOf(alphabetList.size, (idx) / groupMemberCnt)

            when {
                // show Alphabet if
                // 1.alphabet is not running out, and
                // 2. current index match required after shifting
                ((idx-(groupMemberCnt-1)) % groupMemberCnt == 0 && alphabetCntBefore in 0 until 26) -> {
                    val indexAlphabet = alphabetCntBefore
                    ItemAlphabet(alphabet = alphabetList[indexAlphabet])
                }

                //else, number
                else -> {
                    val indexNumber = idx - alphabetCntBefore
                    ItemNum(num = numList[indexNumber])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

